# XML not throwing errors with schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm struggling to understand why my xml and schema aren't working.

Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="animals">
    <xs:element name="animal">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="species"/>
            <xs:element name="name"/>
            <xs:element name="population" minOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:complexType>

    </xs:element>
</xs:element>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<animals xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="animals.xsd">
    <animal>
        <species>reptile</species>
        <name>cobra</name>

    </animal>
</animals>
```

Shouldn't it throw an error because population is missing from the xml file when min occur is 1.

Am i doing everything right?

Answer (score 2):

You're doing several things right.  Here are a few more you might want to add to that list:

- A namespace you create and define should use a domain name you have the right to control.  Unless you own the domain w3schools.com, it would be better practice not to define new namespaces in their space.  If you don't own any domain, and just want an example, the domain example.com is reserved for this purpose.  Or you can write your schemas without target namespaces.
- The xsi:schemaLocation attribute takes as its value not a single URI but a sequence of URI pairs.  In each pair, the first item names a namespace and the second item specifies where the XSD validator can find a schema document for that namespace.  So you want that attribute to look something like this, in your XML document instance:

  ```
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com animals.xsd"
  ```

  Or, if you rewrite the schema document to omit the target namespace, use xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation instead:

  ```
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="animals.xsd"
  ```
- Your schema document currently specifies that its target namespace is `http://www.w3schools.com` and that local elements are fully qualified.  So all the elements in your XML should be in that namespace, if you want your schema processor to recognize that the declarations you show are intended to apply to these XML element instances.  So in your XML, the start-tag for `animals` should say something like

  ```
  <animals xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.w3schools.com animals.xsd
          ">
  ```
- With things as you show them, I would have expected an XSD validator to object to the fact that the value of xsi:schemaLocation did not have an even number of tokens.  If it didn't, then there is the possibility that something went wrong with the way you invoked it; without more information about what validator you're using and how you invoked it, however, it's hard to be sure.
- Most XSD validators begin work in what is known as lax validation mode:  when they see an element in the document for which they have an element declaration, they validate it, and otherwise they skip it (or in some implementations they then examine its children looking for elements they can validate).

  Given a schema describing elements in a particular namespace, and an XML document using elements that aren't in that namespace, an XSD validator started in lax validation mode will not be able to tell whether the elements in the document instance are valid or not.  The XSD specification says that in that case, the `validity` property of the document element has the value `notKnown`.  Most XSD validators issue error messages only on encountering invalid elements, so most XSD validators started in lax mode on a document where nothing matches the schema will not issue any error messages.  It's important not to confuse this with a judgement that the document is valid against the schema; it only means the that document is not *invalid* against the schema.

  If you find this behavior inconvenient or confusing, as many do, you will want to check to see whether the validator you are using allows an invocation-time flag to issue an error, or at least a warning, if the document cannot be confirmed to be valid.   (Conforming XSD 1.1 validators are required to be able to do this; XSD 1.0 is a little hazier on conformance requirements.)  Or the validator may allow you to say that the document is required to have an `animals` element in the `http://www.w3schools.com` namespace and that an error should be raised if it's anything else.  If your validator does not give you any control over how it starts work, let the vendor know that you'd rather have some control, and in the meantime look for a different validator.

[P.S. See also Michael Kay's comment on this answer for another important point to take into consideration.]

Comment: I would just add one thing to Michael's list. Check that you are actually invoking a schema validator. Sorry if that sounds silly, but just adding a schemaLocation to your XML document doesn't automatically turn your XML parser into a schema validator.

Answer (score 1):

Your schema looks wrong - you cannot put `xs:element` directly inside `xs:element` (nor directly inside `xs:complexType`).

I think that what you want is

```
<xs:schema 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
  xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
  elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:element name="animals">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="animal" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="species"/>
              <xs:element name="name"/>
              <xs:element name="population" minOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and then your XML file should use the schema namespace:

```
<animals 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="animals.xsd" 
   xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com">
  <animal>
    <species>reptile</species>
    <name>cobra</name>
  </animal>
</animals>
```